# Get past the proxy when using file_get_contents function

Tags: php

I am running on proxy and when i use function file_get_contents i get error like

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.abc.com/) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\wamp\www\Kurogo123\lib\DataController.php on line 520
```

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a stream context to reach beyond the proxy server. Try this:

```
// Define a context for HTTP.
$aContext = array(
     'http' => array(
         'proxy' => 'tcp://127.0.0.1:8080', // This needs to be the server and the port of the Proxy Server.
         'request_fulluri' => true,
         ),
     );
$cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);

// Now all file stream functions can use this context.

$sFile = file_get_contents("http://www.example.com", false, $cxContext);

 echo $sFile;
```

Comment: It depends, put there your proxy server address

Comment: @bodi0: adding port numbrt is necessary?

Comment: @user123, it is necessary *only* if the port number of the server is *not* 80, but this is almost always the fact, so - yes

Comment: @bodi0: thanks dude. It seems the site has blocked my IP from making request using file_get_contents. Can you please tell me whether this approach can bypass it>

Comment: Put in short - it can, you need however real proxy server with real (and different from yours IP address)